# Decorator to automate "for arg in self.args" process in class methods

Tags: python, class, python-decorators

I created a child class that extends a single parameter from the Parent to `*args` and yields the outputs. However, it looks cleaner with a decorator instead of writing `for arg in self.args: yield` in multiple methods.

```py
# Parent class
class _greet:

    def _hello(self,name):
        return "hello " + name

    def _hey(self,name):
        return "hey " + name

# Child class
class Greet(_greet):

    def __init__(self,*names):
        self.names = names

    def hello(self):
        for name in self.names:
            yield super()._hello(name)

    def hey(self):
        for name in self.names:
            yield super()._hey(name)
```

Although, all of my tries generated an error, because the decorator cannot "find" `self.args`.

---

Edit:
The idea behind this is to get something like:

```py
class Greet(_greet):

    def __init__(self,*names):
        self.names = names

    @args(names)
    def hello(self, var=name):
        super()._hello(var)
```

Comment: Are you sure you need two separate classes for this? You can make the parent handle multiple names; it's only `_greet.__init__` that would need to take a *single* name and put it in its internal list. Then, the only thing the child needs to do is override `__init__` to accept multiple names, rather than just one. `hello` and `hey` work the same (ignoring the different between `return` and `yield`, anyway).

Comment: What kind of decorator, class or function? Also, how to you envision using the child class' methods?

Comment: @chepner The original classes are descriptive statistics in spark. The reason for making 2 classes is a `summary` method that calls 10 methods, so I try to have a single loop instead of 1 per method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, It would be perfect if you could extend your parent-class with desired behaviour.

Secondly, you should think over the meaning of behaviour extending. Functions `_hello` and `hello` are fundamentally different. `_hello` takes **one additional arg** and returns **created output**. `hello` takes **no additional args** and **creates generator**. So may be you don't need to create child class? May be you need to create absolutely independent class (or new function)? Also all your functions in `_greet` doesn't use `self` arg - may be they should be static (via `@staticmethod`)?

Thirdly, are you sure that you need exactly decorators? There are something like 10 idioms I know to emulate same behaviour. Some of them have better productivity, some of them require a small amount of code. Some works with multiple inheritance - some do not. The realisation you have presented (if I understand it correctly) looks like [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) (with mistakes).

Here it is adapter solution:

```
from itertools import repeat

class Greet(object):
    age = 666

    @staticmethod
    def hello(name):
        return f'hello {name}'

    @staticmethod
    def hey(name):
        return f'hey {name}'

    def say_age(self, name):
        return f'{name} is {self.age} years old'

def multiple_greet_adapter(adapter):
    return lambda self: map(adapter, repeat(self), self.names)

class MultipleGreet0(Greet):
    def __init__(self, *names):
        self.names = names

    @multiple_greet_adapter
    def hello_many(self, name):
        return super().hello(name)

    hey_many = multiple_greet_adapter(lambda self, name: super().hey(name))
    say_age_many = multiple_greet_adapter(lambda self, name: super().say_age(name))
```

One of the disadvantages of such implementation is that you still have to write many similar code. Also this not as productive as we want.

Approach 1 - less code, but not productive as well:

```
from functools import partial
class MultipleGreet1(Greet):
    def __init__(self, *names):
        self.names = names

    _corresponding_names = dict(
        hello_many = 'hello',
        hey_many = 'hey',
        say_age_many = 'say_age',
    )

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        try:
            single_greet_handler = getattr(super(), self._corresponding_names[attr_name])
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError()
        else:
            return partial(map, single_greet_handler, self.names)
```

Approach 2 - the same, but with descriptors:

```
class ManyGreets(object):
    def __init__(self, attr_name):
        self._attr_name = attr_name

    def __get__(self, owner_inst, owner_cls):
        if owner_inst is None:
            return self
        else:
            return partial(map, getattr(super(owner_cls, owner_inst), self._attr_name), owner_inst.names)

class MultipleGreet2(Greet):
    def __init__(self, *names):
        self.names = names

    hello_many = ManyGreets('hello')
    hey_many = ManyGreets('hey')
    say_age_many = ManyGreets('say_age')
```

Approach 3 - a good way you can do if `MultipleGreet` is independent class:

```
def _create_many_greets(single_greet_handler, method=True):
    if method:
        return lambda self: map(single_greet_handler, repeat(self), self.names)
    else:
        return lambda self: map(single_greet_handler, self.names)

class MultipleGreet3(object):
    def __init__(self, *names):
        self.names = names
    age = 123

    hello_many = _create_many_greets(Greet.hello, False)
    hey_many = _create_many_greets(Greet.hey, False)
    say_age_many = _create_many_greets(Greet.say_age)
```

Approach 4 - the way I recommend if `MultipleGreet` depends on `Greet`:

```
class ManyGreetsCreator(object):
    def __init__(self, attr_name):
        self._attr_name = attr_name

    def __set_name__(self, owner_cls, set_name):
        attr_name = self._attr_name
        many_greets = lambda s: map(getattr(super(owner_cls, s), attr_name), s.names)
        setattr(owner_cls, set_name, many_greets)

class MultipleGreet4(Greet):
    def __init__(self, *names):
        self.names = names

    hello_many = ManyGreetsCreator('hello')
    hey_many = ManyGreetsCreator('hey')
    say_age_many = ManyGreetsCreator('say_age')
```

Tests:

```
>>> mg0 = MultipleGreet0('Nick', 'John')
>>> mg1 = MultipleGreet1('Nick', 'John')
>>> mg2 = MultipleGreet2('Nick', 'John')
>>> mg3 = MultipleGreet3('Nick', 'John')
>>> mg4 = MultipleGreet4('Nick', 'John')
>>> list(mg4.hello_many())
['hello Nick', 'hello John']
>>> list(mg0.hello_many()) == list(mg1.hello_many()) == list(mg2.hello_many()) ==\
    list(mg3.hello_many()) == list(mg4.hello_many())
True
>>> list(mg0.say_age_many()) == list(mg1.say_age_many()) == list(mg2.say_age_many()) ==\
    list(mg4.say_age_many())
True
>>> list(mg4.say_age_many())
['Nick is 666 years old', 'John is 666 years old']
>>> list(mg3.say_age_many())
['Nick is 123 years old', 'John is 123 years old']
```

You can read more about [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), about [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), about [`super`-class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). There are also approaches based on [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__init_subclass__)